# How to make html numeric input wrap back around

Tags: javascript, html

So my question is, if you have an HTML numeric input with `max={100}` and `min={50}` how can you make it so that if you hit the down arrow when it is set to `50`, to wrap back around to 100. I tried doing this manually by manipulating the onChange handler method, but this messes with the ability to type in the input box, making it so that if I begin to type 100, the first key pressed (1) is below 50 and sets it to 50.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: Use the onkeyup handler and look for up arrow key and down arrow key and handle appropriately.

Comment: thanks @JohnSheridan

Comment: also can't post code. For client.

Comment: If you need help with code you need to post it, or else we can't help, and nor does it qualify as a proper question w/o it. Furthermore, we don't need the client's code, we need a code that reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Something like this:**

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    const min = parseInt(input.min);
    const max = parseInt(input.max);    
    if(e.keyCode === 38 || e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
        e.preventDefault();
        input.value++; 
        if(input.value > max) input.value = min;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 40 || e.code === 'ArrowDown') {
        e.preventDefault();
        input.value--;        
        if(input.value < min) input.value = max;        
    }    
})
```

```css
/* hide spin button */
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    display: none;
}
input[type=number] {
   font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="50" max="100" value="50" autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use closures to keep track of the value in the input and then check the updated values against the elements own `min` and `max` attributes. Something like below:

```js
function ticker(initVal, el, max, min) {
  var currentValue = initVal;
  return function(n) {
    if (currentValue == n) {
      if (n == max) {
        el.value = min;
      } else if (n == min) {
        el.value = max;
      }
    }
    currentValue = n;
  }
}

var target = document.querySelector('#myNumber');
var updateEl = ticker(target.value, target, target.max, target.min);
document.querySelector('#myNumber').addEventListener('click', (e) => updateEl(e.target.value));
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1" max="5" min="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

`change` handler triggers every time the input value changes. You need to use `keyup` handler as John mentioned in the comment.

```js
$('#input').on('keyup', function(e) { // Trigger when a key is pressed and then released
  if (e.which === 38) { // Check if the pressed key is Up Arrow
    var val = $('#input').val();
    if (!isNaN(val)) { // Check if the value is a valid number
      val++;
      if (val > 100) val = 50; // If it exceeds 100, go back to 50
      if (val < 50) val = 100; // Vice versa
      $('#input').val(val);
    }
    else $('#input').val(50); // If the value is not a number, set it to 50
  }
  if (e.which === 40) { // Check if the pressed key is Down Arrow
    var val = $('#input').val();
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      val--;
      if (val > 100) val = 50;
      if (val < 50) val = 100;
      $('#input').val(val);
    }
    else $('#input').val(50);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='input' value="50">
```

Comment: confused what's suppose to be happening here. Don't onChange and keyup both trigger when a single number is typed?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I should check if up arrow is hit while the value === 100, and then set input to 50

Comment: You're right. I've added some comments in the code to explain what each line does.
Also if this answer solves the problem you're facing correctly, can you kindly mark it as accepted? That would give me a few reputations which I need to comment on posts.

Comment: your code doesn't run though. But I think I get it.

Comment: It runs for me... I think you expected the input box to have a number when the code starts? You actually had to input one. But I edited the answer so that it now starts with 50 inside it.

Comment: I expect it to have and up and down arrow. like <input type="number">

Comment: Also enter does nothing. I am sorry man but this other guy has a better answer.

Comment: Ahh..Okay I misunderstood your requirements. Anyways thanks for letting me know what was wrong with this answer. Cheers! :)